# Mac OSX libc++ is missing std::uncaught_exceptions symbol

Tags: c++, macos, libc++, darwin

I noticed that std::uncaught_exceptions symbol is missing from the stock libc++ on my Mac:

```
$ clang++ -v; otool -L /usr/lib/libc++.dylib
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
/usr/lib/libc++.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.0.0)
...
$ nm /usr/lib/libc++.dylib | c++filt | grep uncaught
0000000000007782 T std::uncaught_exception()
                 U ___cxa_uncaught_exception
```

However, the header declares the prototype:

```
$ pwd
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1
$ grep uncaught_exceptions exception
int  uncaught_exceptions() noexcept;  // C++17
_LIBCPP_FUNC_VIS int uncaught_exceptions() _NOEXCEPT;
```

Is this a bad build or something? From the libc++ source I see that the symbol should end up in libc++ but it's not there and I get a missing symbol when linking.

Edit: here is a minimal failing program:

```
$ cat t.cpp; clang++ -std=c++1z t.cpp
#include <exception>

int main () {
    return std::uncaught_exceptions ();
}
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::uncaught_exceptions()", referenced from:
      _main in t-a4015f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: The question is are you actually compiling with `C++17`? in `C++11` it's still the bool `std::uncaught_exception()`, so try using that instead.

Comment: Compilation was done with `-std=c++1z`. The problem is not at compilation stage, where the prototype of std::uncaught_exceptions is visible in the exception header, but at linking time, when the symbol is missing from the library.

Comment: Maybe show how you're using it in your code; I do have a suspicion though that it might be a bug. If you compare the exception header from the llvm trunk with the OS X version there is no `#ifndef _LIBCPP_NO_EXCEPTIONS` declaration as well as `uncaught_exception_count()`... It's unclear if this has anything to do with it. I can compile code with the `c++1z` and `uncaught_exceptions`, although when I try to call the method I get the same error as you.

Comment: I added a minimal program that shows the failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been a while (couple years) since Apple thought it important enough to update libc++.dylib.  I hear rumors it *might* be updated in the OS *after* El Capitan.

What's wrong with *Swift*?! ;-)

Comment: I did not know that. I'll take it as a defect then.

Comment: It's still not updated. `dyld: Symbol not found: __ZdlPvSt11align_val_t
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/verilator/3.912/bin/verilator_bin
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib`

Comment: @Barry  I just checked the OP's minimal failing program on Sierra, 10.12.6 and it passed.  What OS are you testing on?  I'll update this answer with the latest information.